# bgp: session with 79.170.119.177 failed (OPEN Message Error : Unsupported Opt Param

Tags: cisco, bgp

The situation is as follow. I have a Nexus device 5000 family and an IBM blade center with Nortel Layer2-3 GbE Switch Module(Fiber).
These two devices are connected directly. On Nexus I have a vlan Vlan153              79.170.119.177 and on Nortel I have vlan 153 with IP IP: 79.170.119.178.
The IPs are pingable.

I found an issue once I want to setup a bgp session (is and iBGP) and here is the log message from nortel device:

```
bgp: session with 79.170.119.177 failed (OPEN Message Error : Unsupported Opt Param
```

and the bgp session on Nexus is in idle:

```
79.170.119.178  4 25286      28      43        0    0    0 00:27:06 Idle
```

Using a debug command on Nexus side I have the following:

```
Nexus1# debug bgp all

Nexus1# 2014 Dec 25 12:16:01.992881 bgp: 25286 [1191] EVT: Executing bgp_damp_timer_callback
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.192908 bgp: 25286 [1191] EVT: Sent periodic cleanup message to bgp_cleanup_mq
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.192953 bgp: 25286 [1191] EVT: Starting periodic BRIB processing
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.192994 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) BRIB: [IPv4 Unicast] Inspecting prefix 0.0.0.0/0 f or cleanup
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.193029 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) BRIB: [IPv4 Unicast] Inspecting prefix 79.170.112. 0/24 for cleanup
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.193052 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: [IPv4 Unicast] Table cleanup refcount 5
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.193071 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: vrf_ctx cleanup: refcount 4
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.392857 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 peer connection retry timer ex pired
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.393249 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Triggered active open for peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.393294 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 went from Idle to Active (Acti ve setup)
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.395711 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Schedule wait for connect
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.395730 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Wait (5 sec) for session setup response
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967477 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 connect to peer is successful
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967497 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 sending OPEN message to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967513 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 Sending OPEN, version 4, AS 25 286, hold-time 180, router-id 79.170.112.13
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967527 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending (old) dynamic capabili ty (66/0) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967540 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending dynamic capability (67 /3) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967552 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending (old) route refresh ca pability (128/0) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967565 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending route refresh capabili ty (2/0) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967578 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending [IPv4 Unicast] capabil ity (1/4) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967591 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: my restart time 120 restart state 0
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967603 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending graceful restart capab ility (64/6) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967616 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending 4-byte AS capability ( 65/4) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967626 bgp: 25286 [1191] Hexdump at 0x8338d5c, 62 bytes:
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967641 bgp: 25286 [1191]      FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967655 bgp: 25286 [1191]      003E0104 62C600B4 4FAA700D 21021F42
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967669 bgp: 25286 [1191]      00430302 01408000 02000104 00010001
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.967682 bgp: 25286 [1191]      40060078 00010100 41040000 62C6
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.972618 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 went from Active to OpenSent ( Active setup)
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.972646 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Wait (5 sec) for session setup response
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.974110 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: Peer 79.170.119.178 closed connection
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.974129 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Error session closed (during s ession open) in session to peer, value 0, state OpenSent
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.974147 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: [IPv4 Unicast] 79.170.119.178 GR state: none, saved flags: 0
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.974162 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 cleaning up active peer setup, thread id 0x0
2014 Dec 25 12:16:04.974224 bgp: 25286 [1191] EVT: Starting fd_close processing 45702
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.560128 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: Connection request from peer 79.170.119.178 p ort 3196 fd 51, vrf default
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.560944 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 went from Idle to Connect (Pas sive setup)
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.560962 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 sending OPEN message to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.560977 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 Sending OPEN, version 4, AS 25 286, hold-time 180, router-id 79.170.112.13
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.560990 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending (old) dynamic capabili ty (66/0) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561003 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending dynamic capability (67 /3) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561017 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending (old) route refresh ca pability (128/0) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561030 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending route refresh capabili ty (2/0) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561044 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending [IPv4 Unicast] capabil ity (1/4) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561056 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: my restart time 120 restart state 0
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561068 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending graceful restart capab ility (64/6) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561081 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending 4-byte AS capability ( 65/4) to peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561092 bgp: 25286 [1191] Hexdump at 0x8338d5c, 62 bytes:
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561107 bgp: 25286 [1191]      FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561121 bgp: 25286 [1191]      003E0104 62C600B4 4FAA700D 21021F42
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561135 bgp: 25286 [1191]      00430302 01408000 02000104 00010001
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561149 bgp: 25286 [1191]      40060078 00010100 41040000 62C6
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561386 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 went from Connect to OpenSent (Passive setup)
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.561407 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Wait (5 sec) for session setup response
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.974556 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Process OPEN message from peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.974575 bgp: 25286 [1191] Hexdump at 0x8338d5c, 29 bytes:
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.974591 bgp: 25286 [1191]      FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.974604 bgp: 25286 [1191]      001D0104 62C600B4 4FAA77AB 00
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.974624 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.178 sending first KEEPALIVE to pee r
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.976266 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 went from OpenSent to OpenConf irm (Passive setup)
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.976285 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 Wait (5 sec) for session setup response
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.977226 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: Expected first keepalive from 79.170.119.178, got msg type 3
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.977245 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: Received NOTIFICATION unsupported optional pa ram error (0) from 79.170.119.178
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.977267 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: Reset by peer (unsupported optional param err or (0)) in session to 79.170.119.178, value 0, state was OpenConfirm
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.977284 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: [IPv4 Unicast] 79.170.119.178 GR state: none, saved flags: 0
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.977298 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.178 cleaning up passive peer setup , thread id 0x0
2014 Dec 25 12:16:06.977356 bgp: 25286 [1191] EVT: Starting fd_close processing 45703
q2014 Dec 25 12:16:09.502893 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 212.73.206.121 keepalive timer fired for pee r
2014 Dec 25 12:16:09.502918 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 212.73.206.121 sending KEEPALIVE
2014 Dec 25 12:16:09.503650 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 212.73.206.121 next keepalive expiry due in 0 0:00:29

        ^
% Invalid command at '^' marker.
Nexus1# 2014 Dec 25 12:16:12.002923 bgp: 25286 [1191] EVT: Executing bgp_damp_timer_callback
2014 Dec 25 12:16:12.549401 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 212.73.206.121 KEEPALIVE rcvd

Nexus1# 2014 Dec 25 12:16:18.103086 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.162 keepalive timer fired for peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:18.103107 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.162 sending KEEPALIVE
2014 Dec 25 12:16:18.109973 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.162 next keepalive expiry due in 0 0:00:59
2014 Dec 25 12:16:18.110002 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.236 keepalive timer fired for peer
2014 Dec 25 12:16:18.110022 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) ADJ: 79.170.119.236 sending KEEPALIVE
2014 Dec 25 12:16:18.110050 bgp: 25286 [1191] (default) EVT: 79.170.119.236 next keepalive expiry due in 0 0:00:59
```

Did anyone here had a similar situation and does know which parameters is not supported?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

See [RFC 4271 Section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#section-6.2), specifically:

> If one of the Optional Parameters in the OPEN message is recognized,
> but is malformed, then the Error Subcode MUST be set to 0
> (Unspecific).

Ideally debug output from the Nortel would be more useful here, but it's obvious the Nortel isn't liking a BGP capability that the Nexus is sending. There's no real way to tell which of those options is triggering the error unless you get similar debug output from the Nortel device, but I would start with disabling those optional parameters on the Nexus for that peer - stuff like route refresh and/or 4-byte ASNs. Might also help to disable all parameters on the Nexus just to get the BGP session to come up, then start enabling them one at a time until you get the error to figure out which optional capability is causing the problem.